# External images in the Ionic default tab template won’t load in the emulator and on the device

Tags: android, ionic-framework

The tab app template in Ionic contains a few external images, and they won't load when I open the app in my Android emulator or my Nexus 5. Both the device and the emulatir do have internet connection and I can load these images manually in the browser.

It works OK in the browser (ionic serve).

That is:

```
ionic start myApp tabs
cd myApp
ionic serve # OK
ionic platform add android
ionic build android
ionic emulate android # Images are not loaded
ionic run android # Images are not loaded
```

ionic serve:

http://content.screencast.com/users/yuri_l/folders/Jing/media/e95e5f91-c732-414a-9ba5-adaf8a726dd5/00000064.png

Android emulator (Nexus 5):

http://content.screencast.com/users/yuri_l/folders/Jing/media/a515d587-0eea-4978-809d-b800899aa9f9/00000065.png

ionic 1.3.22
cordova 5.0.0

What I am missing?

Comment: probably https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist

Answer (score 6):

Here is the solution:

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

External resources won't load without it.

Answer (score 3):

As joeri said:

> ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist

will fix the issue, Here is the api link to explain how it works. 
[plugin API](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist)

in my cordova config.xml file I have

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

doing this Doesn't block any requests

The API explaination has a few more options if you want to restrict it more, [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist#network-request-whitelist)

Comment: Try to elaborate your answers.Do not just provide on eline answers.Try explaining your answer properly to get more attention.