# ionic framework remote image not loading on android device < 4.4

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, android-4.3-jelly-bean

Hi this issue related to Ionic framework on old android phones <4.4
It only works with existing local images, but not showing the dynamic remote images (e.g. src = 'http://server/xxxx.png')

However this works on **android version => 4.4**.

I also tried cordova-plugin-whitelist but it wont works. plz guide if any other solutions ?

Comment: Which is your cordova version?

Comment: Using the latest cordova 5.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Question solved here: [External images in the Ionic default tab template won’t load in the emulator and on the device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30107751/external-images-in-the-ionic-default-tab-template-won-t-load-in-the-emulator-and)

Using the plugin cordova-plugin-whitelist allows you to load external images on Android and iOS.

Here is how to install it:

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

For iOS, it adds the following entries to your plist.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```